# $P(Y \le X)=\int_0^{\infty} P(Y \le X | X=x)f_X(x)dx$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability, density-function

I was looking at a solution of a probability exercise and the author of the solution uses the formula $$P(Y \le X)=\int_0^{\infty} P(Y \le X | X=x)f_X(x)dx$$ where $X$, $Y$ are the random variables $f_X$ is the density function of the random variable $X$. From where does this result come from?

Comment: It is the [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) for random variables.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know!

Comment: you should  write $P(Y \le X)=\int_0^{\infty} P(Y \le X | X=x)f_X(x)dx=\int_0^{\infty} P(Y \le x | X=x)f_X(x)dx$  when $X=x$ so $\{Y\leq X\}=\{Y\leq x\}$ ($\{Y\leq X|X=x\}=\{Y\leq x|X=x\}$)

Answer (score 2):

This is conditional probability. Remember that
$$
\mathbb{P}[A|B] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[A\cap B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]} \iff \mathbb{P}[A\cap B] = \mathbb{P}[A|B]\mathbb{P}[B]
$$
but if $X$ is continuous, $\mathbb{P}[X=x]=0$, the correct analog being
$$
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \mathbb{P}[x-h\le X \le x+h] = f_X(x).
$$

Comment: Oh thanks. But what does $P(Y \le X \vert X=x)$ mean? I know that by definition $P(A \vert B) = P(A \cap B) /P(B)$ but then this would not make sense since as you say, $P(X=x)=0$

Comment: @roi_saumon You interpret $\{X=x\}$ as the limit I explained in the answer

Comment: So $P(Y≤X|X=x)=P(Y≤X, X=x) f_X(x)$ so that $P(Y \le X)=\int_0^{\infty} P(Y \le X,  X=x)(f_X(x))^2dx$? Isn't that wrong?

Comment: @roi_saumon no, what you want to say is $$\mathbb{P}[Y \le X] = \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}[Y \le X \cap X=x] dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}[Y \le X | X=x] f_X(x) dx$$

Comment: how you guarantee that limit is exist?  is any theorem show that always that limit exist ?

Comment: No, there is no guarantee that the limit will exist. Usually you are safe, but be aware that it is not always so. @masoud  See also things like the [Bertrand Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability))

Answer (score 0):

conditional probability is special case of conditional expectation(definition of conditional probability is based on conditional expectation ).

define:

$A=\{\omega \in \Omega| Y(\omega) \leq X(\omega)\}$

$p(Y\leq X)= p(A)=E(I_A)=E(E(I_A|X))$

$=E(g(X))$ (by definition of conditional expectation ,$E(I_A|X)$  is a function of $X$)

$=\int g(x) f_X(x) dx=\int E(I_A|X=x) f_X(x) dx=\int p(A|X=x) f_X(x) dx=\int p(Y \leq X|X=x) f_X(x) dx=\int p(Y \leq x|X=x) f_X(x) dx$

so you pass the problem with, $p(X=x)=0$ in $p(Y\leq X |X=x)$. since the defination of conditional expectation is based on projection property and not based on $p(A|B)=\frac{p(A \cap B)}{p(B)}$